# Removing subsection's colon in latex

Tags: latex

How can I remove the colon after a specific subsection in latex?

```
\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Cellular Networks}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please ask at http://tex.stackexchange.com instead (but search that site first to see if it is already answered).  When you post there, state which document class you are using.

Comment: By default there are no colons after subsubsections. This question needs a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
```